# Can we use List.Except to confirm a list is subset of another list

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 lists of type long.

List1 with values `{1,2,3,4,5}` and List2 with `{1,4,5,6}`.

Can I use `List2.Except(List1)` to know whether List2 is a subset of List1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `List2` does not contain duplicates, `List2.Except(List1))` will be empty if and only if `List2` is a subset of `List1`.

If your lists can contain duplicates, be warned that this will consider `{1, 1}` a subset of `{1, 2}`, which may or may not be what you want.

NB you can use `.Any()` to easily check if the result of `Except` is empty: `x.Any()` is true if and only if `x` is NOT empty.

Comment: `Except` should be fine, then.